# ASP.NET MVC Transfer HTML Table Contents to Another View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is this do-able?
Here's my situation and could you suggest an easier or more efficient way if what I'm trying to do isn't advisable.
We're talking about report generation page here.First, I have a stored procedure that takes a REALLY long time to finish executing if no filters/condition is set. Meaning it is a view all, this stored proc returns a list. This list then populates a table in my view. It could be just 10 up to thousands records but the execution is pretty long because it computes this and that against thousands of record, to make it short, I won't alter my stored procedure. 
 
Now from this first view, I have a printable version button which calls another page with the same contents but print-friendly page. I dont want to execute the painful stored proc to get the same list, I want to re-use what is already generated. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are thinking of implementing some way of caching the data that you calculated through a painfully slow stored procedure?

One option would be to implement a CacheManager and cache the results for a certain period of time:

```
/// <summary>
/// Cache Manager Singleton
/// </summary>
public class CacheManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The instance
    /// </summary>
    private static MemoryCache instance = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the instance of memoryCache.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The instance of memoryCache.</value>
    public static MemoryCache Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new MemoryCache();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Cache Manager
/// </summary>
public class MemoryCache
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the expiration date of the object
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The no absolute expiration.</value>
    public DateTime NoAbsoluteExpiration
    {
        get { return DateTime.MaxValue; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve the object in cache
    /// If the object doesn't exist in cache or is obsolete, getItemCallback method is called to fill the object
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Object Type to put or get in cache</typeparam>
    /// <param name="httpContext">Http Context</param>
    /// <param name="cacheId">Object identifier in cache - Must be unique</param>
    /// <param name="getItemCallback">Callback method to fill the object</param>
    /// <param name="slidingExpiration">Expiration date</param>
    /// <returns>Object put in cache</returns>
    public T Get<T>(string cacheId, Func<T> getItemCallback, TimeSpan? slidingExpiration = null) where T : class
    {
        T item = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheId) as T;
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = getItemCallback();
            if (slidingExpiration == null)
            {
                slidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            }

            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheId, item, null, this.NoAbsoluteExpiration, slidingExpiration.Value);
        }

        return item;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve the object in cache
    /// If the object doesn't exist in cache or is obsolete, null is returned
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Object Type to put or get in cache</typeparam>
    /// <param name="httpContext">Http Context</param>
    /// <param name="cacheId">Object identifier in cache - Must be unique</param>
    /// <returns>Object put in cache</returns>
    public T Get<T>(string cacheId) where T : class
    {
        T item = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheId) as T;
        if (item == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return item;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Delete an object using his unique id
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpContext">Http Context</param>
    /// <param name="cacheId">Object identifier in cache</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if XXXX, <c>false</c> otherwise</returns>
    public bool Clear(string cacheId)
    {
        var item = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheId);
        if (item != null)
        {
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(cacheId);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Delete all object in cache
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpContext">Http Context</param>
    public void ClearAll(string filter = null)
    {
        var item = HttpRuntime.Cache.GetEnumerator();
        while (item.MoveNext())
        {
            DictionaryEntry entry = (DictionaryEntry)item.Current;
            var key = entry.Key.ToString();

            if (filter != null && (key.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower()) || filter == "*" )) //if filter, only delete if the key contains the filter value
            {
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(entry.Key.ToString());
            }
            else if (filter == null) //no filter, delete everything
            {
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(entry.Key.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I didn't write this myself but can't find the original source.

This is how you use it:

```
// Retrieve object from cache if it exist, callback is performed to set and return object otherwise
UserObject userObject = CacheManager.Instance.Get(httpContext, "singleId", ()=> {
    return new UserObject() {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid()
    };
});

// Retrieve object from cache if it exist, return  null otherwise
UserObject userObjectRetrieved = CacheManager.Instance.Retrieve<UserObject>(httpContext, "singleId");

// Remove object from cache
CacheManager.Instance.Clear(httpContext, "singleId");

// Remove all object from cache
CacheManager.Instance.ClearAll(httpContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your View design is meant to be but you could populate the printable version at the same time and hide it until the button is clicked.